# I have issue with Deployment with jsp file in netbean

Tags: java, jsp

I have funny problem here: Netbeans 6.9.1 cannot deploy some jsp files in my project. Before that, when I created this file, there was no problem, but now I changed something and deployed again, and it does not work even though the file was not changed. I just changed the `href` link on an `a` tag.

The next problem: I have `Product.jsp`, sometimes I put `Product.jsp?id=abc`, it works fine, but using other items it will not work even though it's not bug any error, it just stops the render at line 184 in the JSP file. I cannot understand what happened. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Please ask different questions on different posts.

Comment: have you got some errors? post stacktrace here.

Comment: no, I got no error T.T

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a META-INF folder in your project in Web Pages folder, I noticed that when it's missing web app wont run. Just create the folder and copy the context.xml from another project and edit the path tag.

Hope it helps.